# Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I've got two tables:

```
TableA
------
ID,
Name

TableB
------
ID,
SomeColumn,
TableA_ID (FK for TableA)
```

The relationship is one row of `TableA` - many of `TableB`.

Now, I want to see a result like this:

```
ID     Name      SomeColumn

1.     ABC       X, Y, Z (these are three different rows)
2.     MNO       R, S
```

This won't work (multiple results in a subquery):

```
SELECT ID,
       Name, 
       (SELECT SomeColumn FROM TableB WHERE F_ID=TableA.ID)
FROM TableA
```

This is a trivial problem if I do the processing on the client side. But this will mean I will have to run X queries on every page, where X is the number of results of `TableA`.

Note that I can't simply do a GROUP BY or something similar, as it will return multiple results for rows of `TableA`.

I'm not sure if a UDF, utilizing COALESCE or something similar might work?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### 1. Create the UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CombineValues
(
    @FK_ID INT -- The foreign key from TableA which is used 
               -- to fetch corresponding records
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SomeColumnList VARCHAR(8000);

SELECT @SomeColumnList =
    COALESCE(@SomeColumnList + ', ', '') + CAST(SomeColumn AS varchar(20)) 
FROM TableB C
WHERE C.FK_ID = @FK_ID;

RETURN 
(
    SELECT @SomeColumnList
)
END
```

#### 2. Use in subquery:

```
SELECT ID, Name, dbo.CombineValues(FK_ID) FROM TableA
```

#### 3. If you are using stored procedure you can do like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCombinedValues
 @FK_ID int
As
BEGIN
DECLARE @SomeColumnList VARCHAR(800)
SELECT @SomeColumnList =
    COALESCE(@SomeColumnList + ', ', '') + CAST(SomeColumn AS varchar(20)) 
FROM TableB
WHERE FK_ID = @FK_ID 

Select *, @SomeColumnList as SelectedIds
    FROM 
        TableA
    WHERE 
        FK_ID = @FK_ID 
END
```

Comment: This still feels like a hack. I'm still using subqueries so, there's still a lot of extra processing going on. I'm sure a better solution exists (table restructuring, or another way of looking at the problem).

Comment: I wouldn't call this a hack.  It's more efficient than a cursor would be, and it lacks the overhead that would be necessary to create a temporary table with the data structured the way you want it.

Comment: Shame the columns can't be parameters. As it stands you'll need to make a function for every child relationship!

Comment: That's ok - I need to combine only these particular columns. The rest are 'traditional' joins.

Comment: I don't recall a best way to do this without this method.

Comment: Good stuff, thanks.  I use this to work with the jquery tag-it library.

Answer (score 137):

Even this will serve the purpose

**Sample data**

```
declare @t table(id int, name varchar(20),somecolumn varchar(MAX))
insert into @t
    select 1,'ABC','X' union all
    select 1,'ABC','Y' union all
    select 1,'ABC','Z' union all
    select 2,'MNO','R' union all
    select 2,'MNO','S'
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT ID,Name,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(T2.SomeColumn AS VARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM @T T2 WHERE T1.id = T2.id AND T1.name = T2.name
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') SOMECOLUMN
FROM @T T1
GROUP BY id,Name
```

**Output:**

```
ID  Name    SomeColumn
1   ABC     X,Y,Z
2   MNO     R,S
```

Comment: Nt sure why this hasn't been picked up as it solves the problem without requiring a user function. You can see the same idea expressed here http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/06/25/t-sql-string-aggregate-in-sql-server/ which predates this answer and so might be the "original"

Comment: Same here, not sure why this isn't rated higher

Comment: Hi priyanka, can you tell me if and why the "and t1.name = t2.name" clause is necessary here?

Comment: This is excellent. I was looking to optimise a UDF function as listed in the accepted answer which was killing my server. I went from a 102 second search down to less than 1. Execution plan comparison was 78%-22% but that doesn't relate to the execution time...

Comment: Just a reminder that you'll need that leading ',' or else you'll end up with angle brackets in your output.

Comment: Could you explain this query? Perhaps with links to MSDN also
What does `FOR XML PATH('')` do? I've never seen that before

Answer (score 15):

In MySQL there is a [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function that will return what you're asking for.

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.Name, group_concat(TableB.SomeColumn) 
as SomColumnGroup FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON 
TableB.TableA_ID = TableA.ID
```

Comment: This would've been perfect, if there was a similar function in SQL Server. As it stands, I'm using Ben's solution to hammer together what I want.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are on the right track with COALESCE.  See here for an example of building a comma-delimited string:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string

Comment: Awesome! I had seen some links discussing COALESCE, but they involved creating UDFs with triggers. The link you've submitted has the key, with a single SELECT statement.

I'm adding an answer with the correct solution, so that it's easier for others to find. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ben,

I think the answer needs a bit more detail, namely how to create the UDF, etc. Once I figure this out, I'll add the solution as a community editable answer. Please feel free to edit it, after which I'll accept that as the answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide some more details for a more precise response.

Since your dataset seems kind of narrow, you might consider just using a row per result and performing the post-processing at the client.

So if you are really looking to make the server do the work return a result set like

```
ID       Name       SomeColumn
1        ABC        X
1        ABC        Y
1        ABC        Z
2        MNO        R
2        MNO        S
```

which of course is a simple INNER JOIN on ID

Once you have the resultset back at the client, maintain a variable called CurrentName and use that as a trigger when to stop collecting SomeColumn into the useful thing you want it to do.

Comment: I thought of this, but wasn't very sure if this is an elegant solution - I'd like to have SQL Server return the properly constructed resultset, not something that'll need to be processed further. Would you require additional details? I've simplified the table structure, but I think you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have WHERE clauses on table A create a stored procedure thus:

```
SELECT Id, Name From tableA WHERE ...

SELECT tableA.Id AS ParentId, Somecolumn 
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB on TableA.Id = TableB.F_Id 
WHERE ...
```

Then fill a DataSet ds with it. Then

```
ds.Relations.Add("foo", ds.Tables[0].Columns("Id"), ds.Tables[1].Columns("ParentId"));
```

Finally you can add a repeater in the page that puts the commas for every line

```
 <asp:DataList ID="Subcategories" DataKeyField="ParentCatId" 
DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.CreateChildView("foo") %>' RepeatColumns="1"
 RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="top" 
runat="server" >
```

In this way you will do it client side but with only one query, passing minimal data between database and frontend

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution priyanka.sarkar mentioned and the didn't quite get it working as the OP asked. Here's the solution I ended up with:

```
SELECT ID, 
        SUBSTRING((
            SELECT ',' + T2.SomeColumn
            FROM  @T T2 
            WHERE WHERE T1.id = T2.id
            FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 1000000)
    FROM @T T1
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution below:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_attr_best_weekday_value)as RAVI
FROM content_field_attr_best_weekday LEFT JOIN content_type_attraction
    on content_field_attr_best_weekday.nid = content_type_attraction.nid
GROUP BY content_field_attr_best_weekday.nid
```

Use this, you also can change the Joins

Answer (score -1):

I have reviewed all the answers. I think in database insertion should be like:

```
ID     Name      SomeColumn
1.     ABC       ,X,Y Z (these are three different rows)
2.     MNO       ,R,S
```

The comma should be at previous end and do searching by like `%,X,%`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t.ID, 
       t.NAME, 
       (SELECT t1.SOMECOLUMN 
        FROM   TABLEB t1 
        WHERE  t1.F_ID = T.TABLEA.ID) 
FROM   TABLEA t;
```

This will work for selecting from different table using sub query.