# Oracle: Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, string-aggregation

I'm trying to convert a single-columned subquery into a command-separated `VARCHAR`-typed list of values.

This is identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111341/combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-value), but for Oracle rather than SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an excellent summary of the [available string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php) on Tim Hall's site.

Answer (score 5):

I found this that seems to work.  Thoughts?

```
SELECT SUBSTR (c, 2) concatenated
  FROM (SELECT     SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH ( myfield, ',') c, r
              FROM (SELECT   ROWNUM ID, myfield,
                             RANK () OVER (ORDER BY ROWID DESC) r
                        FROM mytable
                    ORDER BY myfield)
        START WITH ID = 1
        CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ID - 1)
 WHERE r = 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't that break if your ID values are not continuous?

Comment: hmmm, yes I think you're right.  :-(

Comment: I'm not sure why you have both a ROWNUM and a RANK() in your inner query.  You probably only need the RANK() and then START WITH r =  1 CONNECT BY PRIOR r = r - 1.  This doesn't require continuous ID's, since both the ID and the rank are getting generated.

Comment: You do, however, probably want to use ROW_NUMBER() rather than RANK() in general.  In this case it doesn't matter because ROWID is unique, but if you are ordering on a column that can potentially be non-unique, you don't want multiple rows with the same rank.

Answer (score 3):

11.2 introduced [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466), which unlike WM_CONCAT is documented.  A custom aggregate function could also do this.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer I've seen, and is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

Reference: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1186901&#1186901