# Agregate rows in Oracle SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of items stored this way :

```
A1 | B1
A1 | B2
A1 | B3
A2 | B1
A2 | B4
...
```

And I need to retrieve with a SQL Query :

```
A1 | B1, B2, B3
A2 | B1, B4
...
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492563/oracle-combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-valu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 11g Release 2 you can use [`Listagg`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm):

```
Select a, Listagg(b, ', ') Within Group ( Order By b )
From t
Group By a
```

It allows to sort your values, and it already comes with Oracle:

```
A1  B1, B2, B3
A2  B1, B4
```

---

Otherwise you can use the `stragg` function by [Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com), described in [Rows to String](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11591.html).

```
Select a, stragg(b)
From t
Group By a
```

returns

```
A1  B1,B3,B2
A2  B1,B4
```

Comment: Peter, if the OP was on 11gR2 could they use LISTAGG?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have 11g

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
ORDER BY `afield` ASC
```

Use like this

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see how this would help?