# Query to get column value comma separated

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there an Oracle SQL query that aggregates multiple rows into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row)
>   [Agregate rows in Oracle SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667237/agregate-rows-in-oracle-sql-statement)

I am working with Oracle 10g.  I want to have a comma separated String from a column in a table.

e.g.

```
Table  : Customer        
Columns: id and name
```

Data:

```
  id-------name

   1-------John
   2-------Galt
   3-------Howard
   4-------Roark
```

Output of query should be **Jon,Galt,Howard,Roark**

Comment: I believe my requirement is much simpler than the question in the thread you mentioned.

Comment: Here is another relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788011/transpose-select-results-with-oracle (and best answer: http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11591.html ).

Comment: I don't have any grouping to do, I just need the column value extracted to a String.  Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: I believe it's actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667237/agregate-rows-in-oracle-sql-statement

Comment: you have plenty of good answers in the comments, and yes, what you are asking to do is "grouping".  If you wanted the sum of a set of values you'd group by and use sum().  You're asking for something similar but with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it, all I wanted was this:

```
SELECT WM_CONCAT(NAME) FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Marking all comments as +1.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Be aware that WM_CONCAT is, technically, undocumented.  And it requires that Workspace Manager is installed, I believe.

Comment: We use this in production and it works as expected.  One thing to note, if relevant at all, Crystal Reports does not like WM_CONCAT when calling it via SQL Expression, even if you're pointing at a Oracle 10 or greater database.