# SQL Rows concatenation based on single column

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have Table with values

```
X     Y     Z  
-     ---   - 
1     abc   P
1     def   Q
```

I need a normal query (not pl/sql) which can give result as

```
X  Y        Z
-  -------  ---
1  abc,def  P,Q
```

i.e Based on column X the values are converted into csv format

There can be more than three columns.

Comment: what version of Oracle is this? there are `listagr` if you are in Oracle 11g.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Agregate rows in Oracle SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667237/agregate-rows-in-oracle-sql-statement)

Comment: My Oracle version is 10.2.0 ..... 
Its not duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667237/agregate-rows-in-oracle-sql-statement) In that there are only 2 columns ... in this case there can be more than 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can choose any one of the [following techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) to aggregate your strings

> On occasion it is necessary to aggregate data from a number of rows
>   into a single row, giving a list of data associated with a specific
>   value. Using the SCOTT.EMP table as an example, we might want to
>   retrieve a list of employees for each department. Below is a list of
>   the base data and the type of output we would like to return from an
>   aggregate query.
>
> ```
> Base Data:
>
>     DEPTNO ENAME
> ---------- ----------
>         20 SMITH
>         30 ALLEN
>         30 WARD
>         20 JONES
>         30 MARTIN
>         30 BLAKE
>         10 CLARK
>         20 SCOTT
>         10 KING
>         30 TURNER
>         20 ADAMS
>         30 JAMES
>         20 FORD
>         10 MILLER
>
> Desired Output:
>
>     DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
> ---------- --------------------------------------------------
>         10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
>         20 SMITH,FORD,ADAMS,SCOTT,JONES
>         30 ALLEN,BLAKE,MARTIN,TURNER,JAMES,WARD
> ```

Personally, I find this syntax very readable

```
SELECT x, wm_concat(y), wm_concat(z) 
FROM   xyz
GROUP BY x;
```

Comment: +1  There are so many questions on this off-late and good you have given a link to the most elaborate explanation.

Comment: This worked for oracle 10.2.0
Can you please tell me which all version's of oracle have this function

Comment: @C Deepak - I have no idea and a quick search doesn't turn up anything usefull either.

Answer (score 0):

For Postgre you could use something like

```
select X, array_to_string(array_accum(Y), ',') as Y, array_to_string(array_accum(Z), ',') as Z
from Table
group by X
```

It's array_to_string and array_accum are built-in functions.

Comment: I guess OP is talking about Oracle (hence the PL/SQL mention)