# ORACLE SQL listagg function

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

I'm not sure what's going on here, mostly because I've never used this function, but when I use the listagg function on our Oracle 11g database it gives me an ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected.

Here's my SQL

```
SELECT  cdm.courses_id,cde.additional_resources, listagg (dm.delivery_method_desc, ',')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dm.delivery_method_desc) delivery_methods
FROM    tablespace.course_de_delivery_methods cdm,
      tablespace.course_distance_ed cde,
      tablespace.delivery_methods dm
WHERE   cdm.courses_id = cde.courses_id
AND   cdm.delivery_methods_id = dm.delivery_methods_id
GROUP BY cdm.courses_id
```

I haven't a clue why this is breaking.  I was following the example found [here.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_display_multiple_column_values_same_rows.htm)

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure you're db is 11g. You can check via `select banner from v$version;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you using 11.1 or 11.2?  LISTAGG was introduced in 11.2, it was not available in 11.1.

Your SQL statement looks valid to me in 11.2.  But you'd get an error in 11.1 and ORA-00923 would seem like a reasonable error in 11.1.

Comment: I ran the query that Conrad mentioned in the comments and it looks like we're running 11.1 not 11.2.  Thanks man, as soon as the time limit is up I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize this is 11.2 only thing. If I had 11.1 I would have thought it should work.

Comment: This error is coming in 11.2 as well.

    `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
    PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
    CORE    11.2.0.3.0      Production
    TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
    NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production`

Comment: @cyborg007 - What is the query that you are running?

Comment: `select sd.staff_id || ' '||s.staff_name as "Staff Name",
list_agg(d.dept_name,',') within group (order by dept_name) as "Department"
from staff_dept sd
inner join staff s on sd.staff_id=s.staff_id
inner join dept d on sd.dept_id=d.dept_id
group by sd.staff_id,s.staff_name    
having count(sd.staff_id)>1`

Comment: @cyborg007 - The query you posted is calling `list_agg` rather than `listagg`.  Your query is sufficiently different from the query that the original question used that it is probably worth creating a separate question if you can't find your syntax error.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks Justin for the clarification regarding calling the correct function. ListAgg is working perfectly fine.  
I was checking the code posted by Gordon at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620663/query-an-employee-from-two-or-more-departments/16621111#16621111] and was running his query.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave for answered! when i checked my oracle version,found it version is 10G.

Comment: @Vito - See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492563/oracle-combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-val/493016#493016 for alternatives depending on your Oracle version and other constraints.