# Query an employee from two or more departments

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm having an error when executing the query. I don't know what seems to be the problem. I'm trying to query the DB to to find out the staffs from two or more departments. (ie. Staff_ID = 1, works under the DEPT_ID = 4, and 6). There are three tables involved:

```
1. STAFF
2. DEPARTMENT
3. STAFF_DEPT (contains ID of STAFF and DEPT)
```

Here's what I've done,

```
SELECT
sd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME AS "Staff Name",
d.DEPT_NAME AS "Department"
FROM STAFF_DEPT sd
INNER JOIN STAFF s ON sd.STAFF_ID = s.STAFF_ID 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON sd.DEPT_ID = d.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY sd.STAFF_ID
HAVING COUNT (sd.STAFF_ID) > 1
```

Comment: Can we please start with the "error" you're getting?

Comment: @BryanMoyles I created a view on Oracle, and was successful. But when I try to view the View under 'Data', it gave this error failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-04063: view "VU_STAFF_DEPT" has errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your original query:

```
SELECT sd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME AS "Staff Name",
       d.DEPT_NAME AS "Department"
FROM STAFF_DEPT sd
INNER JOIN STAFF s ON sd.STAFF_ID = s.STAFF_ID 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON sd.DEPT_ID = d.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY sd.STAFF_ID
HAVING COUNT (sd.STAFF_ID) > 1;
```

The problem with your query is that you are doing an aggregation on `staff_id`, but you have the columns `staff_name` and `dept_name` in your aggregation.  You are looking for staff in multiple departments.  You can get one row per person with a list of departments using:

```
SELECT sd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME AS "Staff Name",
       list_agg(d.DEPT_NAME, ',') within group (order by DEPT_NAME) AS "Department_List"
FROM STAFF_DEPT sd
INNER JOIN STAFF s ON sd.STAFF_ID = s.STAFF_ID 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON sd.DEPT_ID = d.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY sd.STAFF_ID, s.STAFF_Name
HAVING COUNT (sd.STAFF_ID) > 1;
```

Notice:  I've adding `list_agg()` in the `select` and `s.staff_name` in the `group by`.

If you want one person/department per row, then use a subquery with an analytic function:

```
selectsd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME AS "Staff Name", dept_name
from (select sd.staff_id, s.staff_name, d.dept_name,
             count(*) over (partition by sd.staff_id, s.staff_name) as NumDepts
      FROM STAFF_DEPT sd
      INNER JOIN STAFF s ON sd.STAFF_ID = s.STAFF_ID 
      INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON sd.DEPT_ID = d.DEPT_ID
     ) t
where NumDepts > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The first code suites my need as I wan to get a list of department for one person. But the problem is, I'm not using Oracle 11.2, otherwise it would work perfectly. I'm on Oracle 10g, and it seems I have to use COLLECT :(

Comment: In the analytic function version of the query, `list_agg` should be `listagg`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
with temp as
(select sd.staff_id from staff_dept sd
group by staff_id
having count(staff_id)>1)
select tp.staff_id||' ' ||s.Name AS "Staff Name", d.DNAME
FROM temp tp, 
staff_dept sd,
staff s,
dept d
where tp.staff_id=sd.staff_id
and sd.staff_id=s.id
and sd.dept_id=d.deptno;
```

I have stored the staff_id's having count more than 1 in a temporary view and used it in the final select query.

As I have previously mentioned to techdo that you cannot group by sd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME, d.DEPT_NAME as it would always be unique and would have count as 1 always.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT
  sd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME AS "Staff Name",
  d.DEPT_NAME AS "Department"
FROM STAFF_DEPT sd
  INNER JOIN STAFF s ON sd.STAFF_ID = s.STAFF_ID 
  INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON sd.DEPT_ID = d.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY sd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME, d.DEPT_NAME
HAVING COUNT (sd.STAFF_ID) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried it and no parsing error. However, when I run it, it has no data to view.

Comment: btw, the STAFF_ID is not numerical sequence, it's a varchar (e.g. JB007).

Comment: It does not matter I guess.

Comment: @techdo: You cannot group by sd.STAFF_ID || ' ' || s.STAFF_NAME, d.DEPT_NAME as it would always be unique and would have count as 1 always.