# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected - LISTAGG

Tags: oracle11g, listagg, oracle11gr1

I have to comma separate all the values of a column and for this i am using LISTAGG function, but getting error

> "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Please find below code i am using. Kindly suggest why i am getting this error.

```
select listagg(t.user_email, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.user_email) AS DelimitedEmail
FROM (
SELECT  user_email 
  , sum(LENGTH(user_email)) OVER (ORDER BY user_email) R1
  , row_number() over (order by user_email) rn
from tbl_Users
) t
WHERE t.R1 <= 4000;
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me. Are you **sure** this is the query that causes the error?

Comment: Are you missing 'as' keyword in subquery before 'R1' and 'rn'?

Comment: Yes @Mureinik I am using the exact query but all the time i am getting this error. I have also tried with multiple new sessions as well but no success.

Comment: Hi @Stan tried with keyword 'as' suggested by you but still the error persists :(

Comment: Also the error ie being pointed to be at "Error at Line: 1 Column: 42" which is the end of keyword "WITHIN"

Comment: Which Oracle version? Listagg was introduced in Oracle 11g Release 2

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5569633/266304), if you are actually on 11gR1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aleksej, I am using "11.1.0.7.0". I am trying to comma separate all column values. Also tried "wm_concat" but in many blogs found that this is not recommended. Could you please help me with come suggestions to accomplish this task. Thanks.

Comment: @PS078 - the answer on the linked question has a comment pointing to another question/answer, which refers out to [this often-cited page of alternatives](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques). You could also look through [these related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+string+aggregation+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole