# FROM keyword not found where expected error showed while using listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

```sql
SELECT A, B, C, D, E,
       (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
          FROM B_UNIT
         WHERE SALE_ID = A.SALE_ID
           AND BOOKING_DETAIL_ID < A.BOOKING_DETAIL_ID
           AND RECEIVED = 'N') AS ARREARS_AMOUNT,
       (SELECT LISTAGG('' || BOOKING_DETAIL_ID || '', ',') 
                WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY BOOKING_DETAIL_ID)
          FROM B_UNIT
         WHERE SALE_ID = A.SALE_ID
           AND BOOKING_DETAIL_ID < A.BOOKING_DETAIL_ID
           AND RECEIVED = 'N') AS BOOKING_DETAIL_IDS
  FROM B_UNIT A
 INNER JOIN B_BD_TB B
    ON A.SALE_ID = B.SALE_ID
 INNER JOIN COD_FORM C
    ON B.REGISTRATION = C.FORM
 WHERE A.BOOKING = '4'
   AND A.RECEIVED = 'N'
```

whihch shows the error

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

but I think that I used `FROM` keyword in the right place

Comment: You seem to be on an old version Oracle; `listagg()` was added in 11gR2. What version are you on? [Here are some options](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques). And this is [possibly a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5569633/266304).

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes - query you posted looks OK (see demo below), which means that problem is somewhere else. Might be dummy column names (a, b, c, d, e), or something else - can't tell.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     -- sample tables
  3     b_unit (a,
  4             b,
  5             c,
  6             d,
  7             e,
  8             amount,
  9             sale_id,
 10             booking_detail_id,
 11             received,
 12             booking)
 13     AS
 14        (SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 'N', '4' FROM DUAL),
 15     b_bd_tb (sale_id, registration) AS (SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL),
 16     cod_form (form) AS (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
```

---

```
 17  -- your query
 18  SELECT a,
 19         b,
 20         c,
 21         d,
 22         e,
 23         (SELECT SUM (AMOUNT)
 24            FROM B_UNIT
 25           WHERE     SALE_ID = A.SALE_ID
 26                 AND BOOKING_DETAIL_ID < A.BOOKING_DETAIL_ID
 27                 AND RECEIVED = 'N') AS ARREARS_AMOUNT,
 28         (SELECT LISTAGG ('' || BOOKING_DETAIL_ID || '', ',')
 29                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BOOKING_DETAIL_ID)
 30            FROM B_UNIT
 31           WHERE     SALE_ID = A.SALE_ID
 32                 AND BOOKING_DETAIL_ID < A.BOOKING_DETAIL_ID
 33                 AND RECEIVED = 'N') AS BOOKING_DETAIL_IDS
 34    FROM B_UNIT A
 35         INNER JOIN B_BD_TB B ON A.SALE_ID = B.SALE_ID
 36         INNER JOIN COD_FORM C ON B.REGISTRATION = C.FORM
 37   WHERE     A.BOOKING = '4'
 38         AND A.RECEIVED = 'N';

         A          B          C          D          E ARREARS_AMOUNT BOOKING_DETAIL_
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------------
         2          2          2          2          2

SQL>
```