# SQL result table with Joined row items if the other columns are the same. Help?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Here is my problem:

This is the current result:

```
    |   Name   |  Alias  |   Role   |
        mark       mak       User
        mark       mak       Admin
```

This is the wanted result:

```
    |   Name   |  Alias  |    Role    |
        mark       mak     User, Admin
```

Can this be possible with SQL(using Oracle and Java EE/JPA/Hibernate right now)?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492563/oracle-combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-val)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is a MySQL function.

Here is the SQL for Oracle:

```
  SELECT Name, LISTAGG(Role, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Role) AS Roles
    FROM Your_Table
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on similar questions, this is covered in depth in the following Oracle Base article: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

In short you're either after the `LISTAGG` function or the `WM_CONCAT` function depending on the version of Oracle you're running.