# How to get the grouping output in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I am having two tables:

```
table1 : test1

desc test1

empcode number(6)
qualification_code number(2)

table2 :test2

desc test2

qualification_code number(2)
qualification_name varchar2(10)
```

```
select * from test1
```

```
120633 10
120633 20
120633 30
```

```
select * from test2
```

```
10 BSC
20 MCA
30 MBA
```

I want to select from two tables and I want to get the output as :

```
empcode :120633 Qualification : BSC,MCA,MBA
```

How to get this above output.

Comment: PL/SQL is **only** used for stored procedure in Oracle. You seem to want a SQL solution.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492563/oracle-combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-val)

Answer (score 0):

When I googled "oracle create list from sql", I found ListAgg.  In your case, you would want something like this:

```
select empcode
, ListAgg(qualification_name, ',') 
within group (order by empcode) qualifications
from test1 join test2 on test1.qualification_code = test2.qualification_code
group by empcode
```

I didn't know this but I think it's pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Oracle 11 or higher, you can use the `LISTAGG` function, like this:

```
select empcode
     , listagg(qualification_name, ',') 
          within group (order by qualification_name) as names
from   test1 
join   test2 
on     test2.qualification_code=test1.qualification_code
group by empcode
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use COLLECT

```
select empcode , collect(qualification_name) as qualifications
from   test1 , test2
where  test1.qualification_code = test2.qualification_code
group by empcode
```

you can also use a user defined collection type - very helpful when using with PL/SQL.

Check [this](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306) out (very good blog)