# Oracle Display the values of columns in single row without using connect by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

This is my query

```
 select deptno,ename from emp_task;
```

Output

[image]

I want the output like this

```
eno      ename
20    TRINATH/RABHA
8     SAIKIRAN/KISHORE
10    KUMAR/VICKY/DAFNI
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4686543/1509264), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/492563/1509264), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/468990/1509264) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4686543/1509264) (and probably more).

Answer (score 0):

```
select deptno,
       listagg(ename,'/') within group (order by ename) as names
from temp_task
group by deptno
order by deptno;
```

Comment: @PrabhaChrist: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a766a/1 (and "*not working*"  is not a valid Oracle error message)

Comment: This is the error i got "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 0):

This sql query should work -

```
select deptno,wm_concat(ename) 
from emp_task 
group by deptno 
order by deptno
```

Comment: `wm_concat` is an unsupported and undocumented oracle function (use at your own risk); also its not present in all installations (its not available on any of the 11g instances I run). `LISTAGG` is documented and should be used instead.