# How to make grid results show "<" rather than "&lt;"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, html-entities

This code:

```
SomeField + ' <' + cast(count(AnotherField) as varchar(6)) + '>'
```

Generates the following result in the grid view:

```
Blah &lt;Blah2&gt;
```

How can I ensure the HTML entities show as their character equivalents?  I'm surprised I wasn't able to find a Google answer.

Thanks.

Here's a larger snippet:

```
select
   stuff((
      select
         ', ' + SomeField + ' <' + cast(count(AnotherField) as varchar(6)) + '>'
      from
         SomeTable as SomeAbbrev
      where
         SomeField = SomeOutsideField
      group by
         SomeField
      order by
         SomeField asc
      for xml path('')
   ),1,1,'') SomeFields
from
   blablabla
inner join
   blablabla
left join
   blablabla
left join
   blablabla
order by
   SomeDateField asc
```

Comment: The result needs to be character encoded and unescaped.

Comment: This is in the SSMS grid view for results? I cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: Correct.  It's in a select statement which is inside a stuff().  I can't seem to get around less than or greater than printing in HTML entity form.

Comment: Stuff()? There's no Stuff in your sample so I think we're missing some relevant parts of the query. Can you post the rest?

Comment: Sorry, larger snippet now included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the technique used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202415/sqlxml-without-xml-encoding) or it may be simpler to bypass the XML technique all together and try something like the example below.

This example returns all tables with their columns as a comma delimited string.

```
create function dbo.ColumnString(@table_id int)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @x nvarchar(max)

    select @x = coalesce(@x+',','') + c.name
        from sys.columns c
        where c.object_id = @table_id
        order by c.name

    return @x
end
go

select t.name, dbo.ColumnString(t.object_id)
    from sys.tables t
    where t.type = 'U'
    order by t.name

drop function dbo.ColumnString
```

Comment: Works great!  Any way to include this inside a correlated subquery?  That would be ideal as the list is based on a value in another outside query.

Comment: @MattB: You could encapsulate this logic in a UDF and call the UDF as part of your outer query.

Comment: @MattB: I edited my example to show how to create/use the UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but I works...

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(MyTable.MyColumn, '&lt;', '<'),'&gt;', '>') AS MyColumn
```

Using a UDF to replace a list of html codes could be a little more "clean" solution.

Comment: SomeField + REPLACE('&lt;', '&lt;', '<') still prints in entity form.  :-/  The less than or greater than is my own inserted text, not coming from the DB.

Comment: I have this problem when using a FOR XML statement. Can you post the whole query?

Comment: Query now included in initial post.

Comment: Like I told you, the FOR XML PATH statement in your query is encoding the characters. You can use the solution in the answer above or try to avoid the FOR XML statement using a COALESCE.

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds like I'll need to find a work-around that includes the ability to output comma-delimited list items while also still keeping < and > intact.  I'll have to see if I can find a way to include COALESCE within another select statement.