# SQL Server: convert html tags

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

I decided to ask it here after failing to find answer on my question. I think the solution is easy.

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.*,  
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + '<a href=test.aspx?tab=2&name=wil&item_id=[er.id]>' + er.name + '</a>'
           FROM dbo.role er
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') all
FROM            
    dbo.worker e
```

The only problem is that the output is of the html tags are weird like

```
< = &lt;
& = &amp;
> = &gt;
```

How can I make it normal sign's ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLXML without XML encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202415/sqlxml-without-xml-encoding)

Comment: Look up HTML Entities.

Comment: when i told you in the SQL chat that this question had been asked before many times on stack overflow, i didnt mean create another one

Comment: I didn't understand the answers my knowledge was not that good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type` directive to avoid xml encoding

```
SELECT e.*,
       Stuff((SELECT ','
                     + '<a href=test.aspx?tab=2&name=wil&item_id=[er.id]>'
                     + er.NAME + '</a>'
              FROM   dbo.role er
              FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM   dbo.worker e
```