# group_concat in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111341/combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-value)
>   [Concat groups in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server)

I want to be able to get the duplication's removed

```
SELECT Count(Data) as Cnt, Id
FROM [db].[dbo].[View_myView]
Group By Data
HAVING Count(Data) > 1
```

In MySQL it was as simple as this:

```
SELECT Count(Data), group_concat(Id)
FROM View_myView
Group By Data
Having Cnt > 1
```

Does anyone know of a solution? Examples are a plus!

Comment: You can't `group by` something you use in an aggregate function. I think you mean to `group by id`

Comment: I'm trying to remove dups out of the DB. MSSQL does not make this simple, this is over "searched" and used all the time in DB's task anywhere. 
There should be a way to prevent dups in the first place, but this was not my DB and app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server as of version 2005 and newer, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER` function to eliminate duplicates:

```
;WITH LastPerUser AS
(
   SELECT 
       ID, UserID, ClassID, SchoolID, Created,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Created DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT 
   ID, UserID, ClassID, SchoolID, Created,
FROM LastPerUser
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This CTE "partitions" your data by `UserID`, and for each partition, the `ROW_NUMBER` function hands out sequential numbers, starting at 1 and ordered by `Created DESC` - so the latest row gets `RowNum = 1` (for each `UserID`) which is what I select from the CTE in the SELECT statement after it.

Using the same CTE, you can also easily delete duplicates:

```
;WITH LastPerUser AS
(
   SELECT 
       ID, UserID, ClassID, SchoolID, Created,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Created DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)
DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable t
FROM LastPerUser cte
WHERE t.ID = cte.ID AND cte.RowNum > 1
```

Same principle applies: you "group" (or partition) your data by some criteria, you consecutively number all the rows for each data partition, and those with values larger than 1 for the "partitioned row number" are weeded out by the `DELETE`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `distinct` to remove duplicates. It sounds like you were using `group_concat` to join duplicates without actually wanting to use its value. In that case, MySQL also has a `distinct` you could have been using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(Data) as Cnt, Id
FROM [db].[dbo].[View_myView]
GROUP BY Id
HAVING Count(Data) > 1
```

Also, you can't `group by` something you use in an aggregate function; I think you mean to `group by id`. I corrected it in the example above.

Comment: Thank you @Justin Satyr!
My intention is to use the Data column to group by. Obviously, MSSQL does not allow you to do that. I'm moving from MySQL to MSSQL. I guess I was spoiled!