# Exporting data from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running the EXPORT WIZARD to a flat file on SQL Server 2008.

I am providing a query for this process which grabs data from a view:

```
SELECT [Full Date]
      ,[Year Entered]
      ,[Month Entered]
      ,[Day Entered]
      ,[DOW]
      ,[Week Ending]
      ,[Accession]
      ,[Sales Rep]
      ,[MLNPI]
      ,[IMSNPI]
      ,[IMS Specialty Primary Code]
      ,[Specialty Primary Description]
      ,[IMS Specialty Secondary Code]
      ,[Specialty Secondary Description]
      ,[IMS Specialty Tertiary Code]
      ,[Specialty Tertiary Description]
      ,[IMS Professional ID 1]
      ,[Physician]
      ,[Practice Code]
      ,[MLIS Code]
      ,[Practice Name]
      ,[Date Established]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Address2]
      ,[City]
      ,[State]
      ,[Status]
      ,[order count]
      ,[Order Comments]
      ,[Release Status]
  FROM [SalesDWH].[dbo].[BySpecimenWITHOUTLOMDATA]
  where [Year Entered]=2009
```

I am getting these errors:

```
- Validating (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Full Date" (142) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "DOW" (146) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Week Ending" (147) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Accession" (148) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Sales Rep" (149) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "MLNPI" (150) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "IMSNPI" (151) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "IMS Specialty Primary Code" (152) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Specialty Primary Description" (153) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "IMS Specialty Secondary Code" (154) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Specialty Secondary Description" (155) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "IMS Specialty Tertiary Code" (156) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Specialty Tertiary Description" (157) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "IMS Professional ID 1" (158) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Physician" (159) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Practice Code" (160) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "MLIS Code" (161) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Practice Name" (162) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Address" (164) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Address2" (165) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "City" (166) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "State" (167) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Status" (168) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Order Comments" (170) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on input column "Release Status" (171) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination - 2009_txt" (106)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

I tried to wrap the columns in CAST:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT cast( [Full Date] as nvarchar) as [Full Date],
cast([Year Entered] as nvarchar) as [Year Entered],
cast([Month Entered] as nvarchar) as [Month Entered],
cast([Day Entered] as nvarchar) as [Day Entered],
cast([DOW] as nvarchar) as [DOW],
cast([Week Ending] as nvarchar) as [Week Ending],
cast([Accession] as nvarchar) as [Accession],
cast([Sales Rep] as nvarchar) as [Sales Rep],
cast([MLNPI] as nvarchar) as [MLNPI],
cast([IMSNPI] as nvarchar) as [IMSNPI],
cast([IMS Specialty Primary Code] as nvarchar) as [IMS Specialty Primary Code],
cast([Specialty Primary Description] as nvarchar) as [Specialty Primary Description],
cast([IMS Specialty Secondary Code] as nvarchar) as [IMS Specialty Secondary Code],
cast([Specialty Secondary Description] as nvarchar) as [Specialty Secondary Description],
cast([IMS Specialty Tertiary Code] as nvarchar) as [IMS Specialty Tertiary Code],
cast([Specialty Tertiary Description] as nvarchar) as [Specialty Tertiary Description],
cast([IMS Professional ID 1] as nvarchar) as [IMS Professional ID 1],
cast([Physician] as nvarchar) as [Physician],
cast([Practice Code] as nvarchar) as [Practice Code],
cast([MLIS Code] as nvarchar) as [MLIS Code],
cast([Practice Name] as nvarchar) as [Practice Name],
cast([Date Established] as nvarchar) as [Date Established],
cast([Address] as nvarchar) as [Address],
cast([Address2] as nvarchar) as [Address2],
cast([City] as nvarchar) as [City],
cast([State] as nvarchar) as [State],
cast([Status] as nvarchar) as [Status],
cast([order count] as nvarchar) as [order count],
cast([Order Comments] as nvarchar) as [Order Comments],
cast([Release Status] as nvarchar) as [Release Status]


  FROM [SalesDWH].[dbo].[BySpecimenWITHOUTLOMDATA]
  where [Year Entered]=2009
```

and got error msg:

```
- Setting Source Connection (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0207016: Source - Query [1]: There is a data source column with no name.  Each data source column must have a name.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0207016 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

Comment: if you run your select query with all of the CASTs present, do you get results or are you getting an error?

Comment: @bluefeet returns results no prob

Comment: If you remove the spaces from the columns names in your aliases, do you still get the error?

Comment: @bluefeet yes still getting error!

Comment: Consider trying out the BCP utility (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) instead of the data export wizard. I've had much better success with it than with the clunky U/I for this kind of work.

Comment: @I__  try adding `Set NoCount On` at the beginning of your script

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/6d4eb033-2c45-47e4-9e29-f20214122dd3) the answer is to change all of your columns to the nvarchar datatype.

Comment: thank you bridge. the thing is i dont want to have to change any data types. is it not possible to export data when its not nvarchar

Comment: btw i dont think that answer is right because i change my query to  SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, [Full Date]) etc..... and still same error msg

Comment: You can change the data type in the view rather than the table schema - cast each column to nvarchar in the view definition. My knowledge of the area is lower I'm afraid - but according to that link there is no other way; you need unicode column types.

Comment: @I__ have you done that for all the columns with non-unicode text data types?

Comment: You were doing it correctly before - wrap each of the columns which were throwing errors up in cast or convert statements.

Comment: thanks so much please see my edited question. i tried to do what u said

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Datatypes for the columns in the error message need to be changed to `NVARCHAR`. Since you have a requirement to not modify the view, use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in the query to modify the appropriate columns. I would still ensure the `UTF-8` code page is specified for the destination file just for consistency.

**Original**

In the Import/Export wizard, change the code page to `65001 (UTF-8)` for the file destination.

[image: Destination code page]

Comment: That error message means one of the columns isn't aliased appropriately after the `CAST`. I wasn't able to find it in your query though, double-check the query you used has all columns aliased.

Comment: As an alternative route, go back to the `Destination` window and check the `Unicode` checkbox. At the query screen, remove all the `CAST` functions. Does this work? Worked OK in my testing with a `VARCHAR` datatype column.