# Exporting data to csv from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, type-conversion

I have a SQL Server table that contains columns of type `varchar(MAX)` and I'm trying to get a `.csv` (UTF-8) type export but I get this error instead.

I want to know how I can change this data type to `nvarchar(MAX)` without losing data. Can anyone help?

Messages

> Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on Destination - test_csv.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[test1] is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on Destination - test_csv.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[test2] is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> (many more of the same error - for each column)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I have looked into [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687622/exporting-data-from-a-view), where I have the same problem but I don't know how to use CAST or CONVERT in the query

Comment: What was your sql-statement?

Comment: @akop what do you mean? Includes name, etc. that will be lost if I export it to ASCII, so it must be UTF-8

Comment: *"but i don't know how to use CAST or CONVERT in the query"* where did you get stuck? The data conversion transformation in SSIS is very simple to use for a task like changing the code page.

Comment: @Larnu Idk, I'm newbie sry :( I'm searching for tut about the answers right now

Comment: I'd start at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/data-conversion-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this in 3 ways:

- CAST your source columns to `NVARCHAR` in the initial `SELECT`, e.g. `CAST(mycolumn as nvarchar(column_length))`
- Use a SSIS Data Conversion task to convert the strings to Unicode
- Set Flat File Connection Manager's code page to '1252 ANSI - Latin I'

(65001 Code page = Unicode (UTF-8))

You might find that the 3rd option is easiest.

Comment: data Include names with a language that "1252 ANSI - Latin" won't support it, so i will try other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You should enable Unicode with the checkbox next to the Locale:

[image: Just enable the Unicode it will work, it is beside locale when you select locale]