# how can switch column data into row data using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table like:

```
ID   value
3      1
3      2
3      3
3      4
3      5
3      6
```

Can anyone help me to convert this table into format:

```
ID  Value
3   1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Google `GROUP_CONCAT` + the name of your RDBMS.

Comment: MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, anything else?

Comment: That's not row data, that's a concatenation. Also, group_concat is a MySSL statement not available on SQL Server

Comment: What have you tried already? Can we see some of the SQL code you have written to try and solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct id, 
stuff((select (','+[value]) from Table1 as t2 where t1.id=t2.id 
for xml path('')),1,1,'') as [values]
from 
    Table1 as t1
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dff9e/1)

PS: in example scheme there is `varchar()` type for values, you will need to convert numeric to varchar() if needed.
There are plenty variants to make group_concat in Sql Server, just another way with assembly: [GROUP_CONCAT string aggregate for SQL Server](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/documentation). I found it pretty nice working.
Another way with `COALESCE`

```
DECLARE @values varchar(100)

SELECT @values = COALESCE(@values + ', ', '') + [value]
FROM Table1

SELECT @values
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dff9e/6)

Comment: Does this come from this previous answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111341/combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-value

Comment: There are tons of same examples everywhere.

Comment: Then it's customary to put a link to the previous SO answer

Comment: Another way to flag question as duplicate. Just I couldn't chose and answered directly.

Comment: Hmm, will be quite hard to define 'the previous SO answer' I think... Or could we write a query to determine it?