# Django: make comma separated list based on day name from querySet

Tags: python, django

How can I make a dictionary efficiently from a queryset.

I have days and each day has times associated with it like

Day1 - Time1
Day1 - Time2
Day1 - Time3

Day2 - Time1

I would like to make a `list` of `dictionary` like [{"day":'Day1', "time":'Time1, Time2, Time3'}, ...]

This `join`

```
listof = ",".join(str([ab.day.day, str(ab.time)]) for ab in vqs.clinicDoctor_dayShift.all().order_by('day__id'))
```

gives me string like

```
['Sunday', '15:01:00'],['Sunday', '16:02:00'],['Monday', '09:01:00'],['Monday', '15:01:00'],['Monday', '16:02:00'],['Tuesday', '09:01:00'],['Tuesday', '16:02:00']
```

I would like to have a `list` like this

```
[{'day':'Sunday', 'time':'15:01:00, 16:02:00, 09:01:00'},{'day':'Monday', 'time':'15:01:00, 16:02:00'},{'day':'Tuesday', 'time':'09:01:00, 16:02:00'}]
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values):

```
vqs.clinicDoctor_dayShift.values('day__day', 'time').order_by('day__id')
```

For grouping try [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

raw_result = vqs.clinicDoctor_dayShift.values('day__day', 'time').order_by('day__id')
sorted_result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x.get('day__day'))

result = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted_result, key=lambda x: x.get('day__day')):
    result.append({'day':k, 'time': ','.join(str(item['time']) for item in g)})
```

Comment: It gives me this

[{'time': datetime.time(15, 1), 'day__day': 'Sunday'}, {'time': datetime.time(16, 2), 'day__day': 'Sunday'}, {'time': datetime.time(9, 1), 'day__day': 'Monday'}, {'time': datetime.time(15, 1), 'day__day': 'Monday'}, {'time': datetime.time(16, 2), 'day__day': 'Monday'}, {'time': datetime.time(9, 1), 'day__day': 'Tuesday'}, {'time': datetime.time(16, 2), 'day__day': 'Tuesday'}]


It not group how I mentioned in the question.

Thank you

Comment: @HamidKhan try updated answer. I not tested it, but I hope the main idea will help you.

Comment: It seems to do the grouping. 
One question, is it efficient if this is run in for loop that may have to run 1000+ times? 

I have a querySet that will have many records which all need this sort of grouping. 

Thank you

Comment: @HamidKhan well it's hard to say without test, but sure this will slow down your code, probably you'd better change data structure? Do you really need this kind of grouping?

Comment: Yes. It seems i need that kind of grouping.

I need to show data like I have this pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pceXe.png

Comment: @HamidKhan probably you could fetch data with raw query like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111341/combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-value Not sure if this faster or not.

Comment: I will try that. I am new to Django. Will see how raw SQL works. 

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I went with a loop in the template

```
# views.py
ms = M.objects.filter(foo=bar).all()
for m in ms:
    favorited = m.baz.qux_set.filter(foo=request.user.id).first()
    if favorited:
        m.tags = favorited.tags.names()
```

and

```
# template.html
{% for m in ms %}
  {% for tag in m.tags %}{{ tag }} , {% endfor %}
```